# Hiding ONE category name within Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a category within my Wordpress build that I need to exclude, the category is named 'portfolio' which is being pulled in on another page, but I need the name of that category to be hidden but show any other category names a post is under... I have searched everywhere and found nothing. I also found a plugin but it hasn't been updated for 2 years so I am wary of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the categories are being displayed from within the loop, here is some code that will display all of the categories the post is in, with links to the categories. "Portfolio" should be excluded.

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['slug'] != 'portfolio') {
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
        }
    }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
?>
```

Just replace your current code for displaying the categories with this. Note that this will not affect you site-wide; you will have to manually replace all instances where categories are displayed.